# Accessing Specific key on Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

[image: Firebase Hierachy]

[image: Simulater Screen]

I am trying to update child values within firebase. 
User first will create a new order, it creates two nodes, one in the main orders section and second under user to keep clean records. this seem to have worked but I am struggling to update values

then while he is on the form and makes updates, I want firebase to update simultaneously on firebase. How do I access to that specific key as nothing seem to have worked for me when I tried using observe method.

What will be the best way to access that key that the form is on and update values?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can update values in Firebase:

```
func updateDatabaseForEdits() {

    let updates : [AnyHashable: Any] = ["variableName": value,
                                            "variableName2": value]

    ref.child("COrders").child("specificKeyYouWantToEdit").updateChildValues(updates, withCompletionBlock: { (error, success) in
        if error != nil {
            // upload failed      
            return
        }
        else {
            // upload worked
            // update your locally stored values
        }
    })
}
```

There are other issues with you app though. Specifically, how you're storing the data. How do you expect to know which key to access? I recommend you update your data store to be something like this:

```
desikhanapeena {
    COrder {
        key123 {
            orderInformation
        }
    }

    UserOrders {
        uid {
            key123
                orderInformation
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have questions:

If you want to get the key from a snapshot you can do that like this:

```
for child in snap.children {
    let child = child as? DataSnapshot
        if let key = child?.key {
           // print(key)
        }
}
```

If you want to get the key before you upload you can do that like this:

```
 let key = ref.child("COrders").childByAutoId().key
```

Comment: HI Mate, Thanks for reply, Let me implement this today and come back to you. can you please let me know how do I access "child("specificKeyYouWantToEdit")" portion because that is what I am struggling to pick the key when I am at VC that takes the order. Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: You can get the key when you upload like this let key = ref.child("COrders").childByAutoId().key and the issue is how you data is stored. If you have a user you want to be able to get all of there orders or at least some portion directly. Store the order's using the autoid under the user's uid then just fetch a portion or all of those keys. When you loop over a snapshot you can get the key like this: for child in snap.children {
                let child = child as? DataSnapshot
                if let key = child?.key {
                    // do something
                }
            }

Comment: Thanks mate! that will help heaps... THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

in case if you are still looking for answer.

Answer for Prob #1.
you need to update order value for user, if it successfull then take parent key (in your case , its AutoID) from there , and using this key, update in "Corders".
here is the code

```
func updateBothValue(){
    let value = ["key":"data","key1": "data2"]
    REF.child("Users").child(UID).child("UserCorder").childByAutoId().setValue(value){
        error, ref in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        let key = ref.key
        REF.child("Coorders").child(key).setvalue(value)
    }
}
```

for Prob #2, as you written "access that key that the form is on". for  each form data , store the key which you get from firebase in previous steps. and use this key for updates.